# Replace RestSharp GET request with Net.Http

Tags: c#, restsharp, get-request, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have a RestSharp Entitlement check code that works, but I need to replace it with one that uses native C# library (Net.Http). So I was wondering what will the equivalent of my code be using native C#.

Here is my code:

```
        public static bool Entitlement(string appId, string userId)
    {
        //REST API call for the entitlement API.
        //We are using RestSharp for simplicity.
        //You may choose to use another library.

        //(1) Build request
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(@"https://apps.example.com/");

        //Set resource/end point
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = "webservices/checkentitlement";
        request.Method = Method.GET;

        //Add parameters
        request.AddParameter("userid", userId);
        request.AddParameter("appid", appId);

        //(2) Execute request and get response
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        //Get the entitlement status.
        bool isValid = false;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
            EntitlementResponse entitlementResponse = deserial.Deserialize<EntitlementResponse>(response);
            isValid = entitlementResponse.IsValid;
        }

        //
        return isValid;
    }


    class EntitlementResponse
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AppId { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public async Task<EntitlementResponse> Entitlement(string appId, string userId)
{
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var baseAddress ="https://apps.example.com/";

var api = "/webservices/checkentitlement/"+  userId.ToString()+"/" + appId.ToString();

//or since I don't know how your API looks
var api = "/webservices/checkentitlement?userId="+  userId.ToString()+"&appId=" + appId.ToString()

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntitlementResponse>(json);
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge - thanks for the answer.
I don't know the API of the destination website either. the code I provided used the be working as is. So my question is how can I find out about the API of the website and the other question is that is there any way not to define the API myself, like what is happening in the RestSharp example?

Comment: @ArashNaderpour I am sorry, i am not a professor, I am a software developer, so I don't post any explanations. This is  code that I am using for Get  httpclient reguest. It was tested many times and working properly.